# How to add different footer on pages containing a multipage-table in python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a table which spanning multiple pages and I want to add a footer to these pages like `IDX 1, IDX 2, ...`
Is there any way to do it ?

I genearlly set footer with `document.sections[-1].footer.paragraph[0].add_run("Footer_text")`.

but in this case, how do I get page breaks and set a different footer on each of these pages?

Comment: Each section has its own set of footers. So if you want to change the footer you need to add a new section that starts on a new page. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/sections.html#adding-a-new-section

Comment: @scanny  It worked.. Thanks..
I've added a new section for that table along with a Page field.
Is there a way to reset Page field to 1. Its now taking current page number of document i.e., Section is on page 3 of document so, its taking starting page number as 3..Is it possible to set it to 1? ....There is a way to do it in MSWord by setting start_at='1'....Please help :)